# Spring Data Jpa. How to cleaning data from repositories befor run unit test from particular test classes?

Tags: spring, unit-testing, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have problem with unit tests for persistance stuff written in spring data jpa.

For particular repositories I have a unit tests to be sure that everything works correctly. Also I have a integration tests. Each tests are passed when I run it for particular test classes. But when i run a whole package of tests I got a lot of faliures because I have records inserted into DB from previous tests.

Of course in each test classes I can add @After method to clean each data but I would like to ask that it posible to clean all data from DB before run tests from particular test classes without adding @After method?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Spring's transactional test support to ensure that database changes are rolled back after each test:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx

> One common issue in tests that access a real database is their effect
>   on the state of the persistence store. **Even when you’re using a
>   development database, changes to the state may affect future tests.**
>   Also, many operations — such as inserting or modifying persistent
>   data — cannot be performed (or verified) outside a transaction.
>
> The TestContext framework addresses this issue. By default, the
>   framework will create and roll back a transaction for each test.

Comment: I added @Transactional and @@TransactionConfiguration with roll back setting as true and it works. Thanks!